# How do I get an image from a folder using Ajax and Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express

So, I want to upload a picture and show it right below the page so it looks like I am "posting" the picture.

So here's what I did in **NODEJS**:

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
      destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './public/img');
      },
      filename: function (req, file, cb){
        cb(null, file.originalname);
      }
    });

var upload = multer({storage: storage});

app.post('/', upload.single('file'), function(req, res){
    res.send(req.file);
});
```

So right now every time I upload a picture it goes right into the folder called 'img'.

Now I want to retrieve this img using ajax and that's what I did in **JAVASCRIPT**:

```
$("input[type=submit]").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/',
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

However, I don't get anything from the success function in ajax, rather, I just go to another page where I can see this json:

```
{
    fieldname: "file",
    originalname: "extensao.jpg",
    encoding: "7bit",
    mimetype: "image/jpeg",
    destination: "./public/img",
    filename: "extensao.jpg",
    path: "public/img/extensao.jpg",
    size: 411576
}
```

How can I make this work and receive this JSON in my success function? I thought by doing res.send(req.file) I was already sending the data to my ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

after you've saved the images, you can get them by using this piece of code. This will send the file to the user. Let's say you have a file named `jeff.jpg` inside `./public/img` all you have to is to go to **yourlink.com/files/jeff.jpg** to retrieve it.

```
app.get('/files/:filename', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + 'public/img/' + req.params.filename);
})
```

This means that you can also render the images in your html by only using `img` tag. For example,

`<img src="./public/img/jeff.jpg"/>`

This is the whole code to my main.js file,

```
var express = require('express')
var multer  = require('multer')
var app = express();

var whereFilesAreStored = '/public/img';

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, __dirname + whereFilesAreStored)      //you tell where to upload the files,
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.originalname)
  }
})

var upload = multer({storage: storage,
    onFileUploadStart: function (file) {
      console.log(file.originalname + ' is starting ...')
    },
});

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', function(req, res, next){
    res.render('mult');  //our html document
})

app.get('/files/:filename', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + whereFilesAreStored + '/' + req.params.filename);
})

//file upload
app.post('/post', upload.single('file'), function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.file);
  return false;
})

app.get('/ajax', function(req, res){
  res.render('ajax');
})
```

To use the images in the client side, I have made a file named ajax as you can see above. this is my html.

Using ajax at this point is useless, it is only used to check if there's any updates on a page. But still I have made a small code for ajax for you to see. **Don't use** ajax for this task. you can use `<img src="thelink"/>` to get the file to your page. Please check my img tag down below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Anasayfa</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/cssDosyalari/ana.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var theUrl = 'http://localhost:2222/files/';
      var fileName = "jeff.jpg";
      var wholePath = theUrl + fileName;
      $.ajax({
         type: 'GET',
         url: wholePath + fileName,
         success: function(data){
             console.log(data);
         }
      });
    </script>

    <img src="http://localhost:2222/files/jeff.jpg" alt="">
  </body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**

I have had problems with using ajax to it. Some reason, the link redirects me, so I have came up with this solution. I send the ajax, the server uploads the file, then makes the client reload the page with the image coming out. I am using ejs + ajax in here. Please check the code down below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#my-form').submit( function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    //function myFunc(){
        $.ajax({
          url: '/post',
          data: $('#myFile'),
          cache: false,
          contentType: false,
          processData: false,
          type: 'POST',
          success: function(data){

          }
        })
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log('ajax sent');
      return false;
    //  }
    }
    //onclick="myFunc()"
    </script>

    <form id="my-form" action="/post" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input id="myFile" type="file" name="afile" value="">
      <input  type="submit" name="" value="submit">
    </form>
    <img id="theImgSrc" alt="">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
      $('#theImgSrc').attr('src', 'http://localhost:2222/files/<%=fileName%>').load();
    });
    </script>
  </body>


</html>
```

This is my main.js file,

```
app.get('/files/:filename', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + whereFilesAreStored + '/' + req.params.filename);
})

app.get('/', function(req, res, next){
    res.render('mult', {fileName: ''});  //our html document
})

app.post('/post', upload.single('afile'), function (req, res, next) {
  res.render('mult', {fileName: req.file.originalname});
  console.log(req.file);
})
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for the response. In your example I would have to previously know the name of the img (jeff.png) to make the ajax request. What I want is upload the picture, get te req.file.path in the back-end and then pass it to the front-end via AJAX. But I dont know how to do that. Can you help?

Comment: Please see the update, I've had problems with ajax, sorry, it reloads the page for some reason. but I have tried this thing where it reloads the page and shows us the image as we want it to.